# Python-Bandicoot (Not showing IFrame?)

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
viz_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__)) + '/viz'
bc.visualization.export(U, viz_path)

from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("/files/viz/index.html", "100%", 700)
```

Why is Iframe not showing?

Comment: Please provide more details. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please refer this link - http://bandicoot.mit.edu/demo/   .In here visualization command is not displaying on my project.IFrame is not showing.Thank you